# Access Chrome unsafeWindow

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Yes, you've seen this topic before.** However, Chrome has closed one of the most common *ports* to use the `unsafeWindow` to use with Contents Script.

```
var unsafeWindow;
(function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("onclick", "return window");
    unsafeWindow = div.onclick();
})();
```

Now `div.onclick` returns *null*.

**My question is**: is there another way to access the `unsafeWindow` via Contents Script, currently? For example, I would like to access the jQuery used by the page itself.

```
unsafeWindow.jQuery().jquery; // <- 1.9.0
```

Comment: I believe it's just impossible, because the content script runs in a separate V8 "isolated world" that can't access any of the javascript objects in the main page. You can, of course, include jquery in the list of scripts injected onto the page, with the [content_scripts.js](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) field.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a draft of decision for you. Maybe this is what you need?

*Injected.js* works inside original window scope, *contentscript.js* works inside its isolated window scope. The problem is that you don't have unsafeWindow variable, but I think you can wrap your code inside some function with this variable.

***manifest.json**

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["injected.js"],
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["js/content.js"]
}],
...
```

**contentscript.js**

```
var internalScript = document.createElement("script");
internalScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("injected.js");
document.body.appendChild(internalScript);
```

**injected.js**

```
console.log(window);
console.log(window.$);
```

Comment: It is this line that I am following. But as part of the process, I need to create a communication between the script injected and content script. The problem is they do not "know each other", apparently.

Comment: Do you really need x-communication between them? I thought that you need some kind of Greasemonkey scripts implementation, don't you? If so, it seems like a wrapper function can be implemented quiet simply.

Comment: I need to hack `jQuery.ajax` to apply a `.success()` that will send content to my extension process. Content Script only access *my* jQuery. So I hacked it, but I can't send the `ajax.url` to my Content Script. One of the problems is that neither the Content Script or injected script have access to the `chrome.tabs` API.